# how do we do a cycle in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog language recently started teaching my self this language I came across an interesting question which says to Write a database for a predicate cycle/1 such that query

```
cycle(X)

returns the instantiations
   X = food 
   X = me 
   X = pizza  
   X = food 
   X = me 
   X = pizza 

in an endless cycle
```

How do we do that can someone help me out am trying to touch my self this language!

***hence: it's JUST FOR LEARNING PURPOSES!***

Comment: also, `what(food). what(me). what(pizza). cycle(X):- repeat, what(X).`

Comment: @WillNess can u have a look in the other question i asked ?

Comment: it's gone. :| do you have a link? (even if it's deleted I could see it, but I need a link).

Comment: @WillNess hey there I just undeleted the question would really appreciate your help! here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114028/how-do-we-represent-complex-integers-addition-and-multiplication-in-prolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cycle(food).
cycle(me).
cycle(pizza).
cycle(X):-cycle(X).
```

Comment: It is an endless cycle when you ask for more answers.

Comment: no libraries are used (just auto added by swish you dont need them).