# how do we represent complex integers addition and multiplication in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog language, trying to teach myself. I came across an interesting question which says:

> Represent a complex integer as a two-element list of integers, so `[2,5]` represents *2+5i*.
>   Write Prolog predicates
>
> ```
>  cadd/3
>  cmult/3
> ```
>
> representing complex integer addition and multiplication. Thus for instance,
>
> ```
>  cadd([X1,X2],[Y1,Y2],[Z1,Z2])
> ```
>
> succeeds if and only if `Z1=X1+Y1` and `Z2=X2+Y2`.
>    Note that complex number multiplication is not just like complex number addition.

I'm new to this. Can someone help, I am trying to teach myself. Would really appreciate the help!

***note: it's JUST FOR LEARNING PURPOSES !***

Comment: Hint: With math expressions in Prolog don't use `=` which is unification, use [is](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2), e.g. `X is 2 + 3.`.

Comment: There is a package in SWI, maybe you can look at it: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=plcomplex

Comment: the only easy answer to this is, just write it down, but use `#=` instead of `=` in `Z1=X1+Y1` and `Z2=X2+Y2`. "and" in Prolog is `,`.

Comment: Using a list to represent a complex number is inefficient. Prefer instead a term such as `c(R,I)`. Use `write_canonical/1` on both representations to understand the differences.

Comment: @PauloMoura can u add it in the answer that will be much understandable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment on the complex number representation. Consider:

```
| ?- write_canonical([2,3]).
'.'(2,'.'(3,[]))
yes

| ?- write_canonical(c(2,3)).
c(2,3)
yes

| ?- arg(2, [2,3], Arg).
Arg = [3]
yes

| ?- arg(2, c(2,3), Arg).
Arg = 3
yes
```

The alternative representations can be also visualized as:

```
    c               .
   / \             / \
  2   3           2   .
                     / \
                    3   []
```

Reusing Will Ness answer:

```
:- use_module( library( clpfd)).   % in SWI Prolog

cadd(c(X1,X2), c(Y1,Y2), c(Z1,Z2)) :-
  %% succeeds if and only if Z1=X1+Y1 and Z2=X2+Y2.
  Z1 #= X1 + Y1,
  Z2 #= X2 + Y2.
```

If your Prolog system doesn't support constraints:

```
cadd(c(X1,X2), c(Y1,Y2), c(Z1,Z2)) :-
  %% succeeds if and only if Z1=X1+Y1 and Z2=X2+Y2.
  Z1 is X1 + Y1,
  Z2 is X2 + Y2.
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
    cadd(c(X1,X2), c(Y1,Y2), c(Z1,Z2)) :-
      %% succeeds if and only if Z1=X1+Y1 and Z2=X2+Y2.
      Z1 is X1 + Y1,
      Z2 is X2 + Y2.

user compiled, 4 lines read - 679 bytes written, 1921 ms

| ?- cadd(c(2,3), c(-2,1), C).
C = c(0,4)
yes
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is multiplication follows the same process?

Comment: Different formula, of course, but otherwise similar. Use the same representation for the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As the assignment says,

```erlang
:- use_module( library( clpfd)).   % in SWI Prolog

cadd([X1,X2],[Y1,Y2],[Z1,Z2]) :-
  %% succeeds if and only if Z1=X1+Y1 and Z2=X2+Y2.
  Z1 #= X1+Y1,
  Z2 #= X2+Y2.
```

The `#=`s in Prolog are arithmetic equality constraints. `=` is symbolical unification. `is` is arithmetic assignment / equality checking, but it must be used when all the variables to the right of `is` are already known. `#=` takes care of this automatically.

Comment: that's throw an error it doesn't work ... ?- cadd([2,3],[-2,1],[0,4]).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: cadd/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've edited, and [tested](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ZjqshBzu.pl).

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work it shows the same error also libraries are not allowed is there a simpler way?

Comment: it does work, at the link I provided. you can try it with the `=` instead of the `#=` (and without the line with the `use_module` directive), but it will only work in one direction: `cadd(+A,+B,-C)`. `+` means "is known", `-` means "is not known".